# How to transform a text element so it scales larger left to right?

Tags: css

I'm trying to achieve this look (not the red container, just the text): [image: skewed text]

I've tried using `tranform: scale` and `transform: skew` to no avail, as they pull the entire axis at once and don't allow the input of two arguments for left and right. The only thing left I can think to do is use 3d transform with perspective, but I could not get that to work either.

Terrible example of things I've tried:
https://codepen.io/fortypercenttitanium/pen/YzNLEoR

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-cone">Player 1:</h1>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

.text-cone {
  font-size: 5rem;
/*   transform: scale(1, 0.6); */
/*   transform: skew(0deg, 15deg); */
/*   transform: rotateY(45deg); */
}
```

Comment: Please post your CSS and HTML you have tried. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @disinfor Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with `perspective` and `rotateY`.

Here's an example:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h2 {
  color: black;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  transform: perspective(200px) rotateY(-60deg);
}
```

```html
<h2>Some Text</h2>
```

Comment: I would add `transform-origin:right` and consider a smaller angle

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yeah, you're right. I just wanted to show him a rough idea of achieving the look.